# Using ACTION_VIEW intent to play mp4 from raw folder

Tags: android, xml, android-intent, video, android-videoview

I am unable to get the Action_View intent to play an mp4 from my raw folder. My goal is to use onClick from a button to trigger the playing of a video. I am able to use Action_View to play videos from youtube but haven't had any luck using it to play a local video.

Can someone please give me an example showing the proper formatting required to get this done? If it's not possible, could you suggest another solution? .

Thank you in advanced for any help you can give me!

-YS